# How to localize text in XAML for windows phone

Tags: xaml, localization, windows-phone-8

I am trying to localize strings in `XAML`. So I modified the default string of `ApplicationTitle` in `AppResource.zh-Hans.resx`. After configuring device to proper phone language to Chinese Simplified, the application title shows OK.

However, when I tried to do the same trick to modify title of my pivot item, it doesn't show what I want. I just added a string (`AllSongs`) in the `AppResource.zh-Hans.resx`. and do the following modification. What have I missed? In Solution Explorer, the auto generated "`AppResources.zh-Hans.Designer.cs`" is empty. Do I need to add anything?? Thanks!

```
        <phone:Pivot x:Name="ListView" Title="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Grid.Row="0" SelectionChanged="View_selection_changed" >
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <phone:PivotItem Header="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.AllSongs, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to add the same `AllSongs` to the default AppResource.resx?

If you didn't add it to the default resource file, the designer won't be updated!

Comment: In my case I have had `AppResource.XX.resx` but I just forgot to create `AppResource.resx`